Livewire Volt with Folio App Session Expirey
I have a Livewire Volt class API app with Folio app I am working on. I have the auth middleware in my page as
use function Laravel\Folio\{middleware};
middleware(['auth']);

It is working okay when session expire except I get an alert saying app.test said page expired would you like to refresh In traditional apps with page reload form submit, the page just redirects to login.
        <div>
            <x-text-input name="Todo Name" id="name" wire:model="name" :messages="$errors->get('name')"/>

            <x-date name="Start Date" id="start_date" wire:model="start_date" :messages="$errors->get('start_date')"/>

            <x-date name="End Date" id="end_date" wire:model="end_date" :messages="$errors->get('end_date')"/>

            <div class="flex justify-end">
                <x-button tag="button" wire:click="save()" rounded="md" color="primary" size="md" class="w-40">
                    Save
                    <x-heroicon-s-arrow-right-circle class="w-6 h-6 ml-2"/>
                </x-button>
            </div>
        </div>

Above is how I am submitting data, I tried wire:submit.prevent and got the same result.
